# using boolean flag to neaten up my function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function here hasScrolled:

```
function hasScrolled() {
            var nav = $(this).scrollTop();

            // make sure they scroll more than delta
            if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - nav) <= delta)
                return;

            if (nav > lastScrollTop && nav > headerHeight){
                // scroll Down
                $('.charity-hub-nav').removeClass('hub-nav-down').addClass('hub-nav-up');
            }
            else {
                // scroll Up
                if(nav + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                    $('.charity-hub-nav').removeClass('hub-nav-up').addClass('hub-nav-down');
                }
            }
            lastScrollTop = nav;
        }
```

Just wondering if I can tidy this up using a boolean flag like:

```
 $('.charity-hub-nav').toggleClass('hub-nav-down', 
 flag).toggleClass('hub-nav-up', !flag)
```

This is simply because I want to make this section of code neater and only list the class names once?

Comment: Seems fine to me. It's better than having two sections of code, since you then need to read both to understand how this works and you need to change both if something happens.